# ggplot2 to generate a geom_bar()

Tags: r

I have the following table in **R Studio**, and I am trying to create a `geom_bar()` with `ggplot2` to represent the percentage of students that received financial assistance and those who did not.

```
comparison_table <- data.frame(Students1, Percentage1, financial_assistance1, stringsAsFactors = F)
comparison_table 

           Students1 Percentage1 financial_assistance1
1               PELL   0.4059046                 True
2             NOPELL   0.5018954                 False
3               LOAN   0.4053371                 True
4             NOLOAN   0.2290538                 False
```

My code for the bar plot is:

```
PELL<-mean(na.omit(completion_rate_based_on_financial_assistance$percent_of_students_with_Pell_Grant_and_completed_in_4_years))
NOPELL<-mean(na.omit(completion_rate_based_on_financial_assistance$percent_of_students_without_Pell_Grant_and_completed_in_4_years))
LOAN<-mean(na.omit(completion_rate_based_on_financial_assistance$percent_of_students_with_federal_loan_and_completed_in_4_years))
NOLOAN<-mean(na.omit(completion_rate_based_on_financial_assistance$percent_of_students_without_federal_loan_and_completed_in_4_years))
tab1<-cbind(PELL,LOAN)
tab2<-cbind(NOPELL,NOLOAN)
tab<-rbind(tab1,tab2)
rownames(tab) <- c("PELL","LOAN")
colnames(tab) <- c("With Financial Help","Without Financial Help")

barplot(tab,beside = F,legend.text= rownames(tab),xlab = "Financial Help",col=c("lightblue","pink"))
```

My question is, how can I generate this bar plot using `ggplot2` and `geom_bar()`. For visualization purposes, I wish to generate two stacked bars, one that contains the percentage of students that received Pell Grants and Loans **(PELL & LOAN)** and other bar that contains the percentage of students that did not received Pell Grants and Loans **(NOPELL & NOLOAN)**.

Comment: Suggest you start with a good tutorial [such as this one](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/) and see how you go.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what the "did not receive" column actually mean in this case - how can you have a stacked column for those who didn't receive a loan and those who didn't receive a PELL, when presumably everyone in this column didn't receive either?

Answer (score 0):

```
tb<-data.frame(students1=c("PELL","NOPELL","LOAN","NOLOAN"), percentage1=c(40,50,40,23), financial_assistance1=c(TRUE,FALSE, TRUE, FALSE))
g<-ggplot(tb,aes(financial_assistance1,percentage1))
g+geom_bar(stat="identity",aes(fill=students1))
```

Explanation: It's pretty simple - create the `ggplot` with the x (financial_assistance) and y (percentage) variables, and create the `geom_bar`. Only thing to remember about the `geom_bar` is that it defaults to counting how many cases of "x" and showing that as the bar height. In this case, you want to use the y variable as the value, so that's the `stat="identity"` bit. The `aes(fill=students1)` is there to add the two colours for the stacked bars.

UPDATE: Just noticed I misread what you tried to achieve, edited the code to correct for it.